# Codeigniter form_validation always returns false when trying to submit

Tags: php, codeigniter

I trying to create a basic blog application. I have auto-loaded all helpers needed but every the form_validation check always returns false and does not display any errors.

Controller

```
class Posts extends CI_Controller {

public function create()
{
    $data['title'] = 'Create Post';

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Body', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('posts/create', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    } else {
        $this->Post_model->create_post();
        redirect('posts');
    }
}
```

}

View

```
<h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open('posts/create'); ?>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Title</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Add Title">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Body</label>
<textarea class="form-control" name="body" placeholder="Add Body</textarea>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-secondary">
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with one minor change: check your textarea tag. It's not closed properly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I must have missed it when pasting my initial code but I am still not getting the "required" errors when trying to submit an empty form for example or go to the else case if everything is filled.